# Eigenvectors and equation solution

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Assume that we have the following system of equations:

\begin{equation}
x=Ax
\end{equation}
where $x \in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $A$ is a real $n$ by $n$ square matrix. The problem is to solve for $x$. So, what I thought is that the solution is the eigenvector of matrix $A$ corresponding to the eigenvalue of 1. My question is what happens if such an eigenvector does not exist? Is there not such a vector $x$ that satisfies this relation then? Thanks you!

Comment: Well, the zero vector is always a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously ${\bf x}=\bf0$ is a solution.  If $1$ is not an eigenvector of $A$ then this is the only solution.

Comment: Yes actually forgot to say that we assume that $x$ is not equal to .

Comment: Well in that case the answer is basically the same - if $1$ is not an eigenvalue then there is no solution.  (Comment cut short but I assume you meant ${\bf x}$ is not equal to $\bf0$.)